# C++ Searching a binary tree inside a binary tree of different type

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, tree

These are the functions in the Tree class, I would have a State tree and  Person Tree, and i want to say states->find(fname,lname) in main so TreeType would be of type State since states is of type state. But the error occurs when TreeType is of type Person, although i only call that function when its of type State.

```
Person * find(string fname, string lname, node<Person> * n) {
if(n->data->lname == lname && n->data->fname == fname)
  return n->data;
else if(n->data->lname > lname)
  find(fname, lname, n->left);
else
  find(fname, lname, n->right);
}

Person * find(string fname, string lname, node<TreeType> * n) {
  node<Person> * temp = n->data->people->root;
  Person * p = find(fname, lname, temp);
  if(p != NULL)
    return p;
  find(fname, lname, n->left);
  find(fname, lname, n->right);
}

Person * find(string fname, string lname) {
  return find(fname, lname, root);
}
```

Comment: If you are confused, so will we be. What is the prototype of the function you intend to offer to the user of your class?

Comment: Person * (string fname, string lname);

Comment: its called find sorry

Comment: And your data structure is like a `tree<string, tree<string, object>>` (with a fictive type `tree`)? You should edit your question to add all these details and make it more readable (ie. use spacing and the Shift key and code blocks to display your current code) so that we can answer you without getting a headache trying to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Obligatory sanity check: if you're not doing this for academic reasons, use `std::map`s instead).

Your first `find` overload needs to return the values from the recursive calls, and handle the situation where `n` is a `nullptr`, returning instead of dereferencing it.

```
Person * find(string fname, string lname, node<Person> * n) {
  if (!n)
    return n;
  if(n->data->lname == lname && n->data->fname == fname)
    return n->data;
  if(n->data->lname > lname)
    return find(fname, lname, n->left);
  return find(fname, lname, n->right);
}
```

Similarly in the second overload... you must `return` the values from e.g. `find(fname, lname, n->left);`.

Most compilers will warn you about these kind of mistakes if you enable warnings - e.g. `g++ -Wall` for GCC.

Comment: i actually just checked the null ptrs, nothing

Comment: @Mostafa: it's a strange thing about coding - you usually have to fix all the bugs before it starts working - did you add the return statements too?  If it's still broken, you'll actually having to tell us more than "nothing" if you want further help....